# Entity Framework performance issues

Tags: performance, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I'm having a problem with performance with the entity framework.

Here's the scenario.

I have an entity called "Segment".  Each of these are stored in their own table in the DB.

"Segments" have a custom property called "IsHPMSSegment" which is a calculated field.  It is calculated by calling a stored procedure in the DB that takes the "ID" of the "Segment" and compares some of it's value against values in another table.

One of the queries we need to run is stated as follows: Get me all Segments that are HPMS Segments.

Since the "ISHPMSSegment" value of "Segment" is a custom property, I cannot retrieve it's value directly from the DB when the segments are first selected.  Instead, as each "Segment" is being created in the result set, entity framework queries the db again to get the value for "IsHPMSSegment".  So everytime a "Segment" is being filled, it has to query the DB once again for each Segment returned.

Example:  If I get all "Segments" with an ID greater than 5, and the resultset is 1000 segments, then the DB is hit for a total of 1001 times.  Once for the initial select query that gets the 1000 records, and then another 1000 times to fill the "IsHPMSSegment" value of each of the "Segments".

The only workaround I can think of it to create a view in the DB ("vSegments") that contains this extra calculated property, and then link my EF object to this view, instead of to the "Segment" table.  That way this property would be filled in the first query.

I then have two choices for the remaining functionality (insert, update, delete):
    1) wire up my insert, update, and delete functions for the entity to stored procedures
    2) make the view updatable

All of this seems like a lot of extra work just to address this performance issue, and I'm left wondering what benefit there is to using EF at all?

Is there a better solution to the "view + stored procedures" idea I stated above (still using EF)?

If not, what benefit does EF provide me?  If I was creating my own DAL from scratch, I would still have to create stored procedures and/or views.  How much effort am I really saving by using EF and having to program around it's limitations?

On top of all this, EF doesn't seem to handle updating multiple records at once in a satisfactory way.  It sends a single update statement call for each record you are updating, even if you are updating them all exactly the same.  This also seems to be a detractor (unless there is some workaround for this that I am unaware of).

Comment: Which answerable question in your post would not result in an opinion?

Comment: I suppose I am looking for opinions.

Comment: So let me get this straight.  The issue is that a calculated field needs to be calculated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: I am trying to see how others have solved this performance problem in the past.  Or if it is not resolvable using EF.  This isn't exactly an open-ended discussion.  As with all programming, there are multiple ways to do every action, and all of them could be "opinions" about which way is best.  I'm looking for what others have done to resolve this performance issue.  I suppose the word "opinion" was a bad choice, here.

Comment: My opinion is that you shouldn't call a proc to get the value of a calculated field. You'll have that "performance issue" with or without EF.

Comment: "If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. (You are more than welcome to have such discussions in our real time web chat.) However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK."

Comment: Or even better "Expert programmers interested in professional discussions on software development, ask on Programmers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely subjective. In my option the separation of duties between your layers is getting mixed up and causing you problems.
My suggestion would be to remove your stored procedure and move the logic into you business layer. Creation of your 'segments' should start in your business layer and have all the appropriate logic done against it. The final state can then be pushed into your data access layer for persistence.

Comment: If I move the logic completely into the business layer, I would still have to query the DB for each "Segment" to determine the value of "IsHPMSSegment" because it is determined by comparing some of the "Segment" values against similar values in another table.  It is not something that can be determined just by looking at the values of "Segment" by themselves. So I'd still end up with the performance issue, because it would still query the DB all those extra times to determine the value.

Comment: What about querying the DB for the value, rather than updating DB records you then have to go and re-query? Querying 1000 records should be pretty snappy. Its the round trip where your overhead is. Again, its just my option, but laying out your code to be maintainable is much more important than performance.

Comment: ... especially when the performance gain is small.  CPU, Memory, and storage is cheap now.  Dinosaur programmers like myself have to be reminded of that from time to time.

Comment: Well that's what the view would do.  It would allow me to pull back the value at the time of the first query.  Unless you mean to pull back the full amount of the related table and iterate over it in memory to fill that value.  I suppose that is possible, though I am not sure how I would do that in EF.

Comment: I re-read your post a few times and think I understand now. Instead of making your flag column a calculated field, make it a real field and store the value with the segment. Space is cheap, your time is not. Run your query for a single segment on creation and set that value once in your business layer. Then push it to persistence. Is this acceptable?

Comment: But it is possible for the value to change, when records in the other related table are changed.  Would have to add a trigger to handle it.  This is why I was considering a view, so it would be calculated on the fly each time. .... although, I suppose I could make the field in the DB updated manually each time with a trigger, regardless.  Then I wouldn't have to create SP for the insert, update, delete events.

Comment: I'm not a databaseoligist, so I can't say for sure, but wouldn't a view create a performance problem? Consider creating an object model in your business layer (domain) that would satisfy updating the fields as necessary instead of creating triggers. Some would say best practice is to make the DB as dumb as possible, only know enough to store and retrieve your data. In the end this makes it more manageable.